# Como retirar commits indevidos de uma branch remota?

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit, tortoisegit

A empresa em que trabalho contrata alguns estagiários que cuidam de *tasks* pequenas de varias linguagens e diferentes partes do programa (afim de capacita-los), porém recentemente um dos nossos estagiários fez alguns commits de uma branch em outra no nosso repositório remoto, afim de não excluir a branch, recria-la e fazer as mudanças em alguns commits para maquiar isso, gostaria de saber se existe algum método de:

- "Reescrever" os commits, ignorando aqueles que
  não tem nexo com a branch, refazendo o histórico da branch remota.
- Guardar as alterações feitas nos commits na branch errada, para que no futuro sejam colocadas na branch correta
- Manter o histórico com as alterações na data e hora certa

Estou trabalhando com bitbucket e TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece um caso onde `revert` e `cherry-pick` podem ser bem usados, sem os branches não forem tão diferentes entre si.

Pegue no histório os hashes dos commits feitos no branch errado e faça uma lista.

Depois ainda no branch errado faça: `git revert <hash>` para cada um na ordem inversa (do mais recente pro mais antigo). Isso vai fazer com que o código seja removido do branch errado sem reescrever o histórico, mantendo as alterações como foram - vai criar um commit revertendo cada um dos errados.

Quando tiver o branch novo onde as alterações devem ser aplicadas basta fazer `git cherry-pick <hash>` para cada um dos hashes na ordem certa (do mais antigo pro mais recente). Isso vai aplicar as alterações exatamente como foram feitas no outro branch.

Comment: Acho que vale a pena colocar um adendo para commits mortais, como enviar a senha do banco sem querer no arquivo

Comment: A pergunta falava em manter o histórico e guardar as alterações, não parece ser o caso. A única coisa realmente segura a fazer quando se envia a senha do banco pro GIT é trocar a senha do banco.

Comment: Bem, isso é verdade, mas as vezes a gente faz bobeira e precisa reescrever o histórico. Eu sei que isso é além do que foi pedido pelo @Paz, mas é algo que eu sempre acho importante citar, por neurose mesmo. O GitHub tem [uma postagem sobre esse assunto](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)